# How to convert date format when there are missing/NaT values in the column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, missing-data

I have couple of date columns, I want to convert them to month/day/year format. Let's say test is one of the date columns - below code works.

```
dfq['test1'] = dfq['test1'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

But when there are missing value in the column as 'NaT' it shows error 
ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime . I have created a sample data set and intentionally kept one missing value as ' ' . In that case also it shows error.

I want to keep the missing or NaT values, so can't remove them. Is there any other way around ?

Another question, if I want to convert all my date columns (say test1, test, test3) at the same time, - is there a way to do it while using lambda/strftime ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), which handles `NaT` gracefully:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['2018-01-01', 'hello'])

s = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce')

# 0   2018-01-01
# 1          NaT
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

s = s.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print(s)

# 0    01/01/2018
# 1           NaT
# dtype: object
```

---

For your second question, I do not believe `datetime` to `str` conversion can be vectorised. You can easily do this:

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
    df[col] = df[col].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Or better:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime']):
    df[col] = df[col].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that's a bit more flexible, since it also works with `pd.style.format()`, which is where I encountered the issue. Just wrap the time formatter in a function and catch the error, returning `NaT` when it throws. You can then use whichever time formatting function you want in there.

```
def format_time_nat(t, fmt='{:%d-%b-%y}'):
    try:
        return fmt.format(t) # or strftime
    except ValueError:
        return t

dfq['test1'] = dfq['test1'].apply(format_time_nat)

# when using pd.style.format()
colstyles = {
    'test1' : format_time_nat
}
dfq.style.format(colstyles)
```